# JQuery not getting correct width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used this script to get a width and then apply it to the same element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
    $(".equal-height").each(function(){
        var slideSize = $(this).outerWidth();

        console.log(slideSize);

        $(this).css({ "height" : slideSize + "px" });
    });                
});
```

However, for some reason, there are elements that sometimes don't get a matching width and height. As you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpfgtuzo/5/ the last element has the correct dimensions, but the rest are all higher than their width. I'm trying to get them all to be square and I need to support old browsers too.

This only seems to be an issue when the size of the window is smaller and the four items stack in into a 2 column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comments on other answer,

> I've got numerous elements on the page that use this script and not all are the same size (there are smaller sets of squares too)

And

> but the resulting box isn't coming out square. If you inspect your fiddle, the boxes are ~10px too tall

This solution seems to overcome those problems, Let me know if this helps, [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/cpfgtuzo/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".equal-height").each(function () {
        var slideSize = $(this).outerWidth();

        console.log(slideSize);

        $(this).css({ "height": slideSize + "px", "width": slideSize + "px" }); 
        //setting the width along with height
    });                
});
```

Comment: Downvoters, Please care to comment. The solution is working as expected. Whats the problem?

Comment: This has kind of worked, but the squares are now coming out slightly too large (although the equal heights and widths are great). You can see that the column doesn't go down to 2 wide but stacks each item by 1 as they are now too wide to stack.

Comment: That is because we can resize the view window in Jsfiddle, initially the div's will take 25% width as you have mentioned and then we set the height and width to pixels, I feel when viewed in browser it should be ok, Also you can trigger a window resize event and restructure the divs if you feel the users might resize the window

Comment: This seems to work mostly, but at certain widths, some of the divs are appearing larger than others. For example, I have a row of 4, the first two are 146 width and height, and the last two are coming out at 141.

Comment: hmmm, it must be something related to the media tags which sets the width. With a decent window width it seems to work fine with all divs being equal now in the fiddle, I think the smaller window is not falling under your media css styles and hence the mis alignment.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected in my local code either though. Every solution so far has had a similar issue unfortunately so it could be a general bug.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I think there is a bug with jQuery, when it is calculating the width of each element.

Take [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpfgtuzo/12/) as a workaround.

```
// Height = Width
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $('.wide-content').width();
  // prevent jQuery from calculating the width of children
  $('.wide-content').hide();
  // $(".equal-height").width() is now 50
  var slideSize = $(".equal-height").width() * width / 100;

  $(".equal-height").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "height": slideSize + "px"
    });
  });
  $('.wide-content').show();
});
```

Comment: This has solved my issue of having different heights, but the resulting box isn't coming out square. If you inspect your fiddle, the boxes are ~10px too tall.

Comment: Yeah i can see this, but i don't know, where it comes from. jQuery gives me a different width than firebug. Looks like a bug to me. Could you try this in your code without jsfiddle?

Comment: It's still coming out at incorrect sizes in my own code unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

**Same height on all elements**

I'd just use the first box to calculate the height for the other elements - atleast this would ensure the same height. Also it would get rid of that loop..

```
$(".equal-height").css({"height" : $(".equal-height").eq(0).outerWidth()});
```

*One line to rule them all*

But, since this did not fit the scope..

**Making squares of differently sized elements**

After some messing about it's clear that the widths are returned wrong only after you start tampering with the height. This can easily be tested by commenting out the css-command that sets the height and observing the output.

The solution seems to be to set a predefined height:

```
.link-quarters {            
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    ...
```

This will return the exact same width on all elements (the important part) and you can then set the corresponding height programtically without issues.

*There's still an issue with rounding though, as the percentage-width might result in decimal numbers that gets rounded by the browser (or js).*

https://jsfiddle.net/cpfgtuzo/17/

Comment: That's a good solution but I've got numerous elements on the page that use this script and not all are the same size (there are smaller sets of squares too), hence why the loop was used.